# How can I view power statistics on a desktop computer?

Tags: power-management, system-monitor

I can view power statistics on my laptop by clicking the battery icon in the indicator applet.

How can I access this screen on a desktop computer?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is called gnome-power-statistics. You can launch it from terminal or by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type gnome-power-statistics.

Comment: While your answer isn't incorrect, this app seems to be useless on a desktop. [Here's what mine looked like](http://imgur.com/1PuCP.png).

Comment: Mine did this too until I clicked Processor.